# How to choose a correct in-app type?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval, subscription

I've read all the in-app documentation and I've tired of fighting with App Review Board, that's why I'm asking for your advice.

Please, help me to choose the right type of in-app purchase for my app and to upgrade my app to use a subscription in-app model (non-renewing subscription is also possible).

This app has an entertaiment text and photo content, which is dynamicaly updated twice a day.

I've got a free version, which has:

1. Ads
2. Limitations (limited number of new messages)
3. No photos

And premium-account with:

1. No ads
2. No limitations
3. Photo content

I want to sell this content like subscription (you can buy a premium-account for a period of time), also I've get a mechanism, that allows to use premium-account from every device you have and you can restore your purchases easily, but App Review Board writes:

> The App Review Board evaluated your app and determined that the
>   original rejection feedback is valid. Your app does not comply with:
>
> 11.15
>
> The Purchasability Type for one or more of your In-App Purchase
>   products was inappropriately set.
>
> Your In-App Purchase is currently flagged as Auto-Renewable
>   Subscription. However, it would be more appropriate to use the
>   Non-Consumable In-App Purchase type because the product is used to
>   unlock features of the app. Non-consumable products are only purchased
>   once by users and are always available on all devices that are
>   associated with that user's iTunes account.

How should I change my app to sell my content as subscription?

Comment: Seems like the only way is to explain Apple's App Review Board and make them understand that the purchase unlocks the premium features only for a period of time and that an Auto-Renewable Subscription will be the most appropriate one.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, what is the best way to make them understand that?

Comment: add it to the review notes when you submit the app